# Por que utiliza-se "m" antes de "p" e "b"?

Tags: ortografia

Sabemos que antes das letras "p" e "b" devemos usar "m" em palavras como: pombo, chumbo, limpo, sombra, empada, lamparina, etc.

Por que utiliza-se "m" antes de "p" e "b" ?

Qual a explicação dessa regra?

Comment: Quer dizer, usar o `m` ao invés do `n`?

Comment: E também antes de m: comummente.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

É devido à fonética (veja [consoantes bilabiais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consoante_bilabial)):

Para pronunciar o `m`, é necessário juntar os dois lábios, diferentemente do `n`. 
Como a pronúncia do `p` e do `b` também requerem a junção labial, é conveniente utilizar o `m` antes do `p` e do `b`, como forma de ligação entre as características fonéticas das letras.

Comment: Pelo que li está certo, mas "acredito" que usar "Acredito" torne a sua resposta de "achismo", pesquise sobre "consoantes bilabiais" e complemente a resposta por favor :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Complementado! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Adorei essa informação, não fazia ideia que era esse o motivo, achei que era apenas mais uma das irregularidades inexplicáveis da nossa língua.

Comment: Excelente. Depois desta explicação até parece que consigo mesmo ouvir um pouquinho do **m** em palavras como _tambor_ e _tampouco_ e do **n** em _tento_. Mas o fenómeno que descreves é claramente perceptível no inglês, em que o **m**  e o **n** atrás de consoantes são mesmo pronunciados como consoantes.

Comment: Nunca achei q tivesse um motivo...muito interessante. Apesar de que, pelos menos os brasucas, não pronunciamos o 'm' com junção labial.

Answer (score 0):

A regra diz 
que antes de P e B, só se escreve M.provavelmente por serem letras com pronúncias bilabiais.

Comment: tente trazer alguma referência para sua resposta para ela ser assertiva

Comment: Alescio, antes de responder convém ler as respostas já existentes. Esta tua resposta não acrescenta nada à resposta do falsarela.